# File for preset 'slower' not found in ffmpeg with linux

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

When I am using the below command then getting the error "File for preset 'slower' not found"

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i mainFile.mp4 -ss 00:03:22 -t 00:00:22 -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -vpre slower -crf 18 -aspect 16:9 -r 25 -b 3000k -vpre main -level 21 -refs 2 -threads 0 spliteFile.mp4
```

But when I am trying basic ffmpeg command then it is working fine.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i mainFile.mp4 -ss 0 -t 100 spliteFile.mp4
```

Please suggest. I think I am missing the parameter? thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vpre` is not an alias for the x264/5 encoder preset!

Replace `-vpre slower` with `-preset slower` and `-vpre main` with `-profile:v main`.

Also, `libfaac` is the least recommended AAC encoder. libfdk_aac > aac > lifaac. Your ffmpeg looks to be old, since libfaac is no longer supported in recent versions. I suggest upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. It is working by using below parameters.   
                
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i mainFile.mp4 -ss 00:03:22 -t 00:00:22 -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -preset slower -crf 18 -aspect 16:9 -r 25 -b 3000k -profile:v main -level 21 -refs 2 -threads 0 spliteFile.mp4